# Lightbox doesn't add jquery-plugins.js, while adding Tooltip does

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

The following bit of code doesn't add **jquery-plugins.js**:

```
<p:lightBox styleClass="imagebox">
    <h:outputLink value="../resources/images/car.png">
        <h:graphicImage value="/resources/images/car.png" />                    
    </h:outputLink>
</p:lightBox>
```

This code does add **jquery-plugins.js**:

```
<p:lightBox styleClass="imagebox">
    <h:outputLink id="tip" value="../resources/images/car.png">
        <h:graphicImage value="/resources/images/car.png" />                    
    </h:outputLink>
</p:lightBox>
<p:tooltip for="tip"></p:tooltip>
```

This tooltip has just been added for testing purposes and isn't needed in production. However, it seems that removing it will also break my `p:lightBox` (since **jquery-plugins.js**) won't be included anymore.

I am using templating (`ui:insert`, `ui:define`), the template does use `h:head` and `h:body`. Does anyone know how to fix this (so how to automatically include **jquery-plugins.js** with just `p:lightBox`)?

Note that I have tried multiple versions of Primefaces in which this occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Does anyone know how to fix this (so how to automatically include jquery-plugins.js with just p:lightBox)?*

It's a bug in their `LightBox` component. The resource dependency on `jquery-plugins.js` is missing. See the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.primefaces.org/org.primefaces/primefaces/3.5/org/primefaces/component/lightbox/LightBox.java#35):

```
@ResourceDependencies({
    @ResourceDependency(library="primefaces", name="primefaces.css"),
    @ResourceDependency(library="primefaces", name="jquery/jquery.js"),
    @ResourceDependency(library="primefaces", name="primefaces.js")
})
public class LightBox extends UIComponentBase implements org.primefaces.component.api.Widget {
```

They have to fix it themselves by adding the desired `@ResourceDependency`. Report an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/list) to PrimeFaces.

In the meanwhile, you can workaround it by just explicitly including it in master template.

```html
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" />
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery-plugins.js" />
```

Comment: Great job, thanks again! Will check the source code next time :)